# What does it mean to evaluate the 'inputs' of the Bell polynomial?

Tags: bell-numbers

In page 218 of [this pdf](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Johnson217-234.pdf), the author says if we set $x_i = 1$, we are simply counting the number of partitions of {1,2,3..m} and he says that

$B_{m,k} (1,1,1,1,1..) = mSk$

where $ mSk$ is the Stirling number of second kind

but I don't understand what's the intuition behind this, what exactly happens when we put in values to the polynomial, as in how do we interpret it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combinatorial definition of the Bell polynomial $B_{m,k}$ is a sum over partitions of $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ into $k$ blocks. For each partition of $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ into $k$ blocks of sizes $j_1, j_2, \dots, j_k$, we include a summand $x_{j_1} x_{j_2} \dotsb x_{j_k}$.

When we set $x_1 = x_2 = \dots = 1$, then each of these summands $x_{j_1} x_{j_2} \dotsb x_{j_k}$ also simplifies to $1$. As a result, $B_{m,k}(1, 1, \dots, 1)$ is also a sum over partitions of $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ into $k$ blocks, but for each partition, we simply add $1$, regardless of what the sizes of the blocks are.

A sum of many $1$s just simplifies to however many $1$s there are. In this case, it simplifies to the number of partitions of $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ into $k$ blocks, which is exactly what the Stirling number of the second kind $\{{m \atop k}\}$ counts.